# Makefile: Rule dependent on directory of target

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to create a Makefile to create object files in a directory based on the source file. For example I have `DirA/file.c` and `DirB/file.c` and I want to create a recipe for creating `DirA/file.o` and `DirB/file.o`.

```
rootdir/
|-- Makefile
|-- DirA
|    |-- source.c
|    +-- source.o
+-- DirB
    |-- file.c
    +-- file.o
```

I would assume the recipe would be similar to the following:

```
MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules
DirA_Files=$(wildcard DirA/*.c)
DirB_Files=$(wildcard DirB/*.c)

.PHONY: all a_files b_files
all: a_files b_files
    @echo Done with all!
    @echo built $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(DirA_Files)) $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(DirB_Files))

a_files: $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(DirA_Files))
b_files: $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(DirB_Files))

DirA/%.o DirB/%.o : DirA/%.c DirB/%.c
    # Complex recipe that I'd rather not state twice in the Makefile
    @echo "Building $@ because $? changed"
    @touch $@
```

But I do not want the object files in `DirA` to be dependent on the source files of `DirB`, which is what the above recipe implies.

I have also tried

```
DirA/%.o : DirA/%.c
DirB/%.o : DirB/%.c
DirA/%.o DirB/%.o :
    # Complex recipe that I'd rather not state twice in the Makefile
    @echo "Building $@ because $? changed"
    @touch $@
```

But then the `$?` variable is always blank.

How could I create a single recipe that would also allow me to build `a_files` and `b_files` independently

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine pattern rules quite that easily. But this situation is what [defined recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes) were made for:

```
define complex-rule
# Complex recipe that I'd rather not state twice in the Makefile                                                            
@echo "Building $@ because $? changed"
@touch $@
endef

DirA/%.o : DirA/%.c
        $(complex-rule)

DirB/%.o : DirB/%.c
        $(complex-rule)
```

Comment: You don't even need different pattern rules: if you want the object files in the same directory as the source files you can just use a single pattern rule as Milag vaguely alludes to in their answer by using the built-in implicit rules (although a bit more detail there would help make this clearer).  It's only if you want the object file and source file to be in different directories _from each other_ that you have to create a special rule for each directory.

Answer (score 0):

related info:

```
DirA_Files := $(wildcard DirA/*.c)
DirB_Files := $(wildcard DirB/*.c)

$(info DirA_Files: $(DirA_Files))
$(info DirB_Files: $(DirB_Files))

aobj := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(DirA_Files))
bobj := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(DirB_Files))

$(info aobj: $(aobj))
$(info bobj: $(bobj))

all: $(aobj) $(bobj)
        @echo Done with all!
```